# Converting LiDAR .las to .xyz with LAStools outputs incorrect projected coordinates?

Tags: coordinate-system, lidar, utm, xyz, lastools

I have an application that can import terrain data in an XYZ text format where X = latitude, Y = longitude and Z = elevation.

I am trying to convert a LiDAR .las file to this format using [las2las](https://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/download/las2las_README.txt).

I use `las2las` to convert the .las file and then read the converted .las file in Python using `laspy` to read the XYZ values.  The X and Y values do not reflect the proper latitude/longitude of the area that the LiDAR file contains.

To illustrate, here is the .xml from the LiDAR file showing metadata, note that latitude around 46.XXXXXXXX and Longitude -96.XXXXXXX (which is what I expect):

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<Metadata>
<EntityID>IWI_RedRiver-C_2008_000723</EntityID>
<ProjectName>IWI_RedRiver-C_2008</ProjectName>
<ProjectMetadataFiles>http://dds.cr.usgs.gov/lidar_v2/ND-MN/2008/IWI_RedRiver-C_2008/metadata/IWI_RedRiver-C_2008_metadata.zip</ProjectMetadataFiles>
<State>ND-MN</State>
<BeginDate>2008-04-21</BeginDate>
<EndDate>2008-05-16</EndDate>
<VerticalDatum>NAVD88</VerticalDatum>
<MapProjection>UTM</MapProjection>
<MapZone>14</MapZone>
<MapProjectionDefinition>PROJCS["NAD_1983_UTM_Zone_14N",GEOGCS["GCS_North_American_1983",DATUM["D_North_American_1983",SPHEROID["GRS_1980",6378137.0,298.257222101]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0.0],UNIT["Degree",0.0174532925199433]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["False_Easting",500000.0],PARAMETER["False_Northing",0.0],PARAMETER["Central_Meridian",-99.0],PARAMETER["Scale_Factor",0.9996],PARAMETER["Latitude_Of_Origin",0.0],UNIT["Meter",1.0],AUTHORITY["EPSG",26914]]</MapProjectionDefinition>
<CenterLat>46.8520722</CenterLat>
<CenterLon>-96.8356110</CenterLon>
<ULLat>46.8613222</ULLat>
<ULLon>-96.8483721</ULLon>
<URLat>46.8608250</URLat>
<URLon>-96.8221249</URLon>
<LRLat>46.8428221</LRLat>
<LRLon>-96.8228554</LRLon>
<LLLat>46.8433194</LLLat>
<LLLon>-96.8490916</LLLon>
<MinX>664000.000</MinX>
<MaxX>665999.990</MaxX>
<MinY>5189999.998</MinY>
<MaxY>5191999.989</MaxY>
<MinZ>253.551</MinZ>
<MaxZ>330.992</MaxZ>
<VendorID>IWI_RedRiver-C_2008_R06645190</VendorID>
<NumOfPulseRecords>2559425</NumOfPulseRecords>
<NumOfPulsesByReturn>(1) 2424977 (2) 129573 (3) 4807 (4) 68</NumOfPulsesByReturn>
<NumOfPtRecords>2559425</NumOfPtRecords>
<NumOfPtsByReturn>(1) 2491531 (2) 66447 (3) 1442 (4) 5</NumOfPtsByReturn>
<Intensity>0,255</Intensity>
<NominalPulseSpacing>1.28432</NominalPulseSpacing>
<PulseDensity>0.60625</PulseDensity>
<PulseDensityNPSUnits>METER</PulseDensityNPSUnits>
<VendorNominalPulseSpacing>1.7</VendorNominalPulseSpacing>
<VendorPointDensity>.35</VendorPointDensity>
<VendorPointDensityNPSUnits>METER</VendorPointDensityNPSUnits>
<FileFormat>las</FileFormat>
<LASVersion>1.0</LASVersion>
</Metadata>
```

The LiDAR file I am trying to get lat/long from is called IWI_RedRiver-C_2008_000723.las so I run `las2las` with these parameters:

```
las2las -i c:\terrainfiles\lidar\IWI_RedRiver-C_2008_000723.las -o out.las -utm 14N -target_latlong
```

I get XYZ values in this range:

```
X,Y,Z:  8433152 -8240716 27584
```

It is not close to what I'm expecting from the .xml file (which is the correct lat/lon).

Am I using `las2las` wrong? I have tried other `las2las` params such as -epsg 26914, and -sp83 ND_S and I get different X,Y,Z values but still off.

For Example:

```
las2las -i c:\terrainfiles\lidar\IWI_RedRiver-C_2008_000723.las -o out.las -utm 14N -sp83 ND_S -target_latlong
```

produces :

```
X,Y,Z:  4590852 505294 27624
```

I see `las2txt` appears to do what I want from my Python script but it gives a completely different outcome as well. If I run it on the previous output of `las2las` with this command:

```
las2txt -parse xyz -i out.las -o out.xyz
```

I get output that looks like this:

```
86.4590852 -94.9494706 276.24
86.4590849 -94.9492982 276.24
86.4590847 -94.9491291 276.32
86.4590845 -94.9489549 276.24
86.4590842 -94.9487867 276.28
86.4590869 -94.9489067 284.62
86.4590894 -94.9488187 276.20
```

Is there a better way to convert LiDAR .las to XYZ where X and Y are latitude/longitude values?

Comment: Instead of using 14N, try using 14T. Based on example [here](https://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/download/las2las_README.txt), it uses the latitude band letter rather than the hemisphere letter.

Comment: This appears to work using las2txt, if you put this down as an answer I will mark the questions as answered.

Comment: Done! Thank you for letting me know that it worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't expect that this would be the answer, but it turns out that `las2las` uses the UTM latitude band letters rather than the hemisphere 'N' (North) or 'S' (South) letters with the zone number. While not stated directly, I found an example in this [help page](https://www.cs.unc.edu/~isenburg/lastools/download/las2las_README.txt)

Here's an example from that page:

```
>> las2las -i s1885565.laz -o out.las -sp83 OH_S -feet -elevation_feet -target_sp83 OH_N -target_survey_feet -target_elevation_survey_feet 
>> las2las -i TO_core_last_zoom.laz -o out.laz -utm 17T
>> las2las -i TO_core_last_zoom.laz -o out.laz -utm 17T -target_latlong
```

Note the '-utm 17T'. The 'R', 'S', and 'T' bands are solidly in the contiguous  United States (AKA lower 48). You can check out Wikipedia for more information on the [latitude bands](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system#Latitude_bands_2).

In this particular case, instead of using 14N, try using 14T.